# Socket io communication blocked by CORS policy in a Node js + Angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, cors

So I use a simple node.js server with express and socket.io
When I try to communicate with a simple client written in javascript, it works perfectly, but when I try to create the communication with an Angular app (using ngx-socket-io), I get the following error message :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQFEnVV' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is the nodejs server :

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.set(port, process.env.PORT);
app.use(express.static('./client/'));

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.emit('connection', 'data from server!');
});
 
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port ' + port);
});
```

And this is how I implement socket.io on Angular client :

app.module.ts :

```js
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const hostname = window.location.hostname;
const url = (hostname === 'localhost') ? `${window.location.protocol}//${hostname}:5000` : undefined;
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url, options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
```

class that use socket io :

```js
constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

    this.socket.on('connection', (data) => {
      console.log('Working ' + data);
    });
```

I tried to fix the CORS error with headers in server side such as :

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});
```

or

```js
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
     response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     next();
});
```

but it still display the same error.

I use of course the command `ng serve` to run my application (running on port 4200) and it was perfectly working 3 months ago. (Working with the ng serve, and the ng build prod as well).

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verify socket.io-client version on the angular `packaje.json` file. If it's lower than 3.1.2 you could try to upgrade it by
`npm install socket.io-client@3.1.2 --save`
Also you could verify the serverside once again looking at this

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origins: ['http://localhost:4200']
    }
});
```

Replace `http://localhost:4200` by your current environmment on the Angular App

Comment: You saved my day ! Works well with socket.io and ngx-socket-io 4.0

Comment: Problem solved, thank you a lot :)
The ngx-socket-io was above 3.1.2, but when I add the cors origins as you showed, it worked just fine, no cors policy problems anymore. Thank you!

Comment: if you are using es6 notation  use this const io = new Server(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  },
});

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:4200",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
  });
```

you can add or remove mothods

also try adding this

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Still deosn't work, sorry :/ The problem seems to be related to Angular or ngx-socket-io

Comment: i have updated the answer, can you try that also and sorry if that doesn't work either..

Comment: Same, still does't work, I already tried as much as fixes possible server side, still doesn't work :c

Answer (score 0):

Adding fix from Angular side (no changes in Node server required).

That  `cors: { origins: ['http://localhost:4200']}` didn't work for me so I sat up a proxy file in Angular project to tackle CORS.

add file in src/proxy.config.json file

```
{
    "/api": {             // this attaches /api/ in api url
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    },
    "/": {               // use this as second entry
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

in angular.json, add this;

```
"serve": {
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "move-safe:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.json"
          },
```

and re-build the angular app

Answer (score -2):

It worked on the local machine but didn't on production.

I was confused why is that happening but suddenly i noticed that the HEROKU deployed it on something like

https://dummydomain.herokkuapp.com

but i was trying to connect it from

http://dummydomain.herokkuapp.com

that may be the reason for your app as well.

:D